# ASP test site 404s on UnityWebRequests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-game-engine, http-status-code-404

I want to test linking a Unity project with an ASP site. Both the Unity project and the site are prototypes, running locally. The problem is, sending a `UnityWebRequest` 404s on my local site. I have tried standalone builds and WebGL builds embedded on the site, and both fail with a `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` error message. Both builds can reach public URLs like `www.example.com`.

Here is the relevant Unity code:

```
public void SendRequest()
{
    string url = "https://localhost:12345/Index";
    StartCoroutine(GetRequest(url));
}
    
IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
{
    using (var uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        uwr.certificateHandler = new CertificateApprover();
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
        while (!uwr.isDone)
            yield return null;
        Debug.Log("From " + uwr.url);
        if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Received: ");
            byte[] receivedBytes = uwr.downloadHandler.data;
            for (int i = 0; i < receivedBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.Log("\t" + receivedBytes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is in a `MonoBehavior` class, and `SendRequest` is called by the UI on button press.
The `CertificateApprover` is set to approve my localhost's self-signed certificate, as follows:

```
public class CertificateApprover : CertificateHandler
{
    private static readonly string PublicKey = "redacted for brevity";

    protected override bool ValidateCertificate(byte[] certificateData)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateData);
        string pk = certificate.GetPublicKeyString();
        if (pk.Equals(PublicKey))
            return true;
            
        return false;
    }
}
```

The ASP project is pretty much straight from the MVC template; I've not installed any special packages or made any modifications outside the `Startup.cs` to allow WebGL files when I was testing that. The contents of that class for reference:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        AllowWebGl(app);
    }

    private void AllowWebGl(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        StaticFileOptions option = new StaticFileOptions();
        var contentTypeProvider = (FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)option.ContentTypeProvider
            ?? new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".mem", "application/octet-stream");
        contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".data", "application/octet-stream");
        contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".memgz", "application/octet-stream");
        contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".datagz", "application/octet-stream");
        contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".unity3dgz", "application/octet-stream");
        contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".jsgz", "application/x-javascript; charset=UTF-8");
        contentTypeProvider.Mappings[".json"] = "application/json";
        contentTypeProvider.Mappings[".unityweb"] = "TYPE/SUBTYPE";
        option.ContentTypeProvider = contentTypeProvider;
        app.UseStaticFiles(option);
    }
}
```

My first hunch was ASP might be blocking Unity somehow, so I've tried commenting out the `services.Configure` block, as well as the `UseHttpsRedirection()` and `UseCookiePolicy()` lines. Still, Unity 404s on my site, while being able to reach `www.example.com` and other public sites.

I haven't found much documentation on UnityWebRequests and HTTPS, so another guess is Unity could be downgrading my requests to HTTP, and my site is rejecting the requests because it's trying to serve HTTPS only.

My last guess is related to my browser. I'm launching the site in debug mode through IIS in a window of the latest version of Firefox. But I doubt it could be related to this, since the web requests were failing even when the Unity project was embedded in the site itself.

Comment: Sure its not Index.aspx ? Rather than just Index?

Comment: I can paste the URL into my browser, and it loads perfectly fine. I can change the view to Index, Privacy, etc., and the ASP application can recognize the url without adding an .aspx or .cshtml suffix.